# How to put command line arguments, into args for execve

Tags: c, exec

Hello I need help with this assignment. I've been wondering how to put command line arguments(argv[1], argv[2] ...) into my arguments array so it will work in my `execve` function.

I've managed to do it without them. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char* input = argv[1];
  char* output = argv[2];
  int call, ac;
  if ((ac = access(output, F_OK)) == 0) {
    printf("file already exists");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  char* bin = "/bin/bash";
  char* const args[] = {bin, "-c", "tr a-z A-Z < input.txt > output.txt", NULL};
  if ((call = execve(args[0], args, NULL)) == -1) {
    perror("error!");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Now i wanna know, how I can change my args like this:

```
 char* const args[] = {bin, "-c", "tr a-z A-Z < argv[1] > argv[2]", NULL};
```

Basically instead of `input.txt` and `output.txt`, I would like argv[1] and argv[2].

Comment: A suitably large character array and `snprintf` would be perfect for that.

Comment: I'm new to C so good luck to me with that...

Comment: Do you know about `printf`? The `snprintf` function is similar, but instead of writing to the standars output, the `snprintf` writes the result to an array of characters. Any decent book or tutorial should have mentioned at least `sprintf`, and `snprintf` is a safer version of `sprintf` where you can't go out of bounds of the destination array.

Comment: Also see e.g. [this `printf` and family reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: Did you consider doing the I/O redirection in your code, opening the files and then running `tr` directly?  There'd be no need to create the Bash command line that way — you'd just have `char *args[] = { "tr", "a-z", "A-Z", NULL };` and appropriate calls to `open()` and `dup2()` (and `close()`).